# How to add a hidden sidebar that only shows when clicked or hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a hidden sidebar on my website. This is what exactly what I want to achieve: http://demo.themebeans.com/pinto/ but I wanted it to show in hover instead of click. <strike>just instead of a click... just want my visitors to just hover on it.</strike>

Here's what I have so far. I want it to be positioned the same with the sample I've given above. :( Can someone help?

```
#nav{width:200px;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:100;background:#111;color:#fff;overflow:hidden;}
#nav ul{margin:0;padding:0;width:200px;margin:10px;list-style:none;}
#nav a span{margin:0 10px 0 0;}
#nav a{color:#fff;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('#nav').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({width:'200px'},500);
},function(){
    $(this).animate({width:'35px'},500);
}).trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
Contents of the sidebar like the one on my sample. 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yztJ8/ here's the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the absolute positioning correctly:

```
#nav { position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; }
```

Just change `left: 0;` to `right: 0;` - here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yGBkV/

I strongly recommend you use the **hoverIntent** plugin - the user experience will improve a lot:

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: hi. but how do I make the height auto resize with the browser? http://shericaocbania.org/chiara/

Comment: I don't see any problem with the height... at least using Chrome the `height: 100%` is working fine when resizing.

Comment: Hi @j. Bruni . Everything's working thanks much! The only problem I have is how do I use and implement the plugin you sent?

Comment: Just add the plugin Javascript file and use `hoverIntent` instead of `hover` - see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gx4KA/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mix of pure JS and jQuery.

```
(function() {
    var oNav = document.getElementById('nav');
    oNav.addEventListener('hover', function() {
        $('#nav').fadeIn();
    }, false);
})();
```

This probably should work.

Answer (score 0):

simply try

```
$('#nav1').bind("mouseenter", function() {
    $('#nav').animate({width:'200px'},500);
});
$('#nav1').bind("mouseleave", function() {
    $('#nav').animate({width:'0px'},500);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yztJ8/5/